# Hunk #1 FAILED at 53

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm creating an android application in python script using python-for-android

while creating the application in pycharm , i had got some errors and even i don't have any idea of why these errors are causing

```
[INFO]:    Prebuilding six for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    six has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Prebuilding pyjnius for armeabi-v7a
[INFO]:    pyjnius has no prebuild_armeabi_v7a, skipping
[INFO]:    Applying patches for pyjnius[armeabi-v7a]
[INFO]:    Applying patch sdl2_jnienv_getter.patch
[INFO]:    -> running patch -t -d /home/veluvijay/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds...(and 167 more)
           working: 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej                                              Exception in thread background thread for pid 13494:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/veluvijay/envs/imagetotext/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 2170, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/veluvijay/envs/imagetotext/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 1929, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/veluvijay/envs/imagetotext/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sh.py", line 672, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/patch -t -d /home/veluvijay/.local/share/python-for-android/build/other_builds/pyjnius-python2-sdl2/armeabi-v7a/pyjnius -p1 -i /home/veluvijay/envs/imagetotext/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonforandroid/recipes/pyjnius/sdl2_jnienv_getter.patch

  STDOUT:
patching file jnius/jnius_jvm_android.pxi
patching file setup.py
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file setup.py.rej


  STDERR:
```

Answer (score 0):

patching file setup.py
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53.

your patch file is causing an error , you probably need to delete it or change it.